# How to sort and group domtree for select option list

Tags: c#, sorting, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

ASP.NET Core 7 MVC & C# shopping cart controller gets DPD pickup point list using

```
  using HttpClient client = new() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ftp.dpdbaltics.com") };
  var domTree = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<JsonNode>("PickupParcelShopData.json");
```

Result is array of objects sorted by `parcelShopId` property:

```
[
  {
    "parcelShopId": "EE90001",
    "legacyShopId": "190001",
    "parcelShopType": "PickupStation",
    "companyName": "Automat 1 place xxx",
    "companyShortName": "Automat1",
    "street": "\u00D5ism\u00E4e tee 46",
    "houseNo": "",
    "addressLine2": "London",
    "countryCode": "UK",
    "zipCode": "13512",
    "city": "Tallinn",
    "longitude": "24.64727",
    "latitude": "59.411726",
    "openingHours": [
      {
        "weekday": "Monday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "Tuesday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "Wednesday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "Thursday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "Friday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "Saturday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      },
      {
        "weekday": "Sunday",
        "openMorning": "0001",
        "closeMorning": "1200",
        "openAfternoon": "1200",
        "closeAfternoon": "2359"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parcelShopId": "EE90002",
    "legacyShopId": "190002",
    "parcelShopType": "PickupStation",
    "companyName": "Automa3 xxx ",
    "companyShortName": "Automa3",
    "street": "Endla 45",
    "houseNo": "",
    "addressLine2": "Riga",
    "countryCode": "EE",
    "zipCode": "10615",
    "city": "Riga",
    "longitude": "24.7227",
    "latitude": "59.42714",
    "openingHours": [
 ....
```

Razor view renders select element from it using

```
<select id='dpd_select'>
@foreach ( var esi in domTree.AsArray() ) {
  <option value='@esi["parcelShopId"]'>@esi["companyName"]</option>
}
</select>
```

It is difficult to find pickup point from this order.

How to order and group by select element option list by 3 properties:

```
 countryCode
 city
 companyName
```

Should domTree be sorted and grouped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for a select list

```
     var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);

       var selectList = jArr
          .Select(x => new JObject
          {
              ["countryCode"] = x["countryCode"],
              ["city"] = x["city"],
              ["parcelShopId"] = x["parcelShopId"],
              ["companyName"] = x["companyName"]
          })
          .OrderBy(x => x["countryCode"])
          .ThenBy(x => x["city"])
          .ThenBy(x => x["companyName"]);
```

or using system.text.json

```
 var jArr = JsonArray.Parse(json).AsArray();

       var selectList = jArr
          .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
              ["countryCode"] = (string) x["countryCode"],
              ["city"] = (string) x["city"],
              ["parcelShopId"] =  (string) x["parcelShopId"],
              ["companyName"] =  (string) x["companyName"]
          })
          .OrderBy(x => x["countryCode"])
          .ThenBy(x => x["city"])
          .ThenBy(x => x["companyName"]);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. However it requires Newtonsoft.Json.dll assembly. How to implement this in pure .NET 7, using classes from System.*  and maybe from Microsoft.* namespaces?